# Is there any Map / GIS application that generates map images with symbols on Longitude Latitude

Tags: maps, latitude-longitude

I need a map application or API that can load customized symbols on world map, using longitude and latitude and also generate output image of the map.

Web API, won't work for me because i will be loading a very huge number of symbols, millions of symbols (It freezes browser and doesn't generate image).

Answer (score 0):

Generic Mapping Tools (GMT) http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/

Mapyrus http://mapyrus.sourceforge.net

both of these solutions are free but require some programming to define what data you want to read, and what output you want to generate.